# How do I properly give props to the copyright holder (Creative Commons) of an image I use in an answer?

Tags: discussion

In this answer: [Can I increase RAM from 8GB to 16GB on this model?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/380733/93229) I use an image from ifixit. The copyright holder (Sam Goldheart) uploaded it under the Creative Commons BY-NC-SA licence there ([Image Metadata](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/NarKemP5uHIdcOIE)).

Does anyone have a template to quickly add all necessary copyright details to an image I use in an answer?

I have done it this way:

> I don't know how to properly credit Sam Goldheart and the pic he made. Here is the [image metadata page](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/NarKemP5uHIdcOIE) with the licence [Creative Commons BY-NC-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0) (and larger versions of the pic).

which isn't very convenient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>I didn't have anything written up previously, but it's a good opportunity to come up with something. Please feel free to comment, contribute, and critique as needed - let's make this a canonical question/answer.</sub>

**Important: I am not a lawyer.  Nothing in here should be construed as legal advice or a legal opinion in any way. These are my interpretations of the Creative Commons license and my opinions only.  They do not reflect the opinions of StackExchange, it's employees, or its community members.**

---

### Not all sites use the same license...

The problem with attribution is that it varies by content source.  If we're using the iFixit site, all of their content is covered by the [Creative Commons BY-NC-SA 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/), not the [current version 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/legalcode).  This is actually a good thing because iFixit makes things easy for us.

> **All iFixit content is licensed under the Creative Commons BY-NC-SA 3.0 license.**

Source:  https://www.ifixit.com/Info/Licensing

You can summarize the requirements as *attribution reasonable to means, media and context.*  To simplify that into human readable form:

#### ***Attribute the work where/when possible such that it's reasonable to do so.***

### iFixit Attribution Template...

I've come up with a footnote template you can use to attribute.  You can reference them with an asterisk (`*`) or other common symbols like plus`﹢` or hyphen `-`.  If using more than one image, Arabic numerals (1, 2, 3....) is sufficient.

Use this footnote template (items in braces `{}` are optional):

```
<hr>
<sup>#</sup> Source:  [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com) (Photo credit: {Owner Name}, {Work Title}, {Copyright} and licensed under [CC BY-NC-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/). {Adapted for this answer by <indicate mods>}
```

So, adapting this for attributing to iFixit specifically:

```
<hr>
<sup>*</sup> Source:  [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/Qayrd2rbwLCQQoZv). Photo credit: Sam Goldheart and licensed under [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/).
```

This is your template so save this for future use.  Just change the author's name and source image URI as needed.

Here's what the rendered output would look like (using values from the original question):

---

<sup>*</sup> Source:  [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/Qayrd2rbwLCQQoZv). Photo credit: Sam Goldheart and licensed under [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/).

---

#### Why so short?

- Link to the original photo is provided.
- Link to the license as provided by iFixit
- No modifications were made
- We only have the author's name
- No copyright notice, no title, ToS, etc.

If there had been some modifications - adding some arrows to point to components for example - the phrase *Adapted for this answer; see arrows and highlights for emphasis*

Rendered output with notification of adaptation:

---

<sup>*</sup> Source:  [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Image/meta/Qayrd2rbwLCQQoZv). Photo credit: Sam Goldheart and licensed under [CC BY-NC-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/). Adapted for this answer; see arrows and highlights for emphasis.

---

### CC BY-NC-SA Quick Summary

Here's a quick summary of what v4.0 of the [CC license](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Detailed_attribution_comparison_chart) requires:

- Creator name, if supplied
- Copyright notice, if supplied; disclaimer of warranties, if supplied
- Title, if supplied
- Notice that refers to Public License
- Notice that refers to disclaimer of warranties if supplied
- URI or link to material if supplied
- Indication you modified the material
- Indicate material is available under Public License and include the link

The key to remember is that you only need to include what is available and what is reasonable to include.  For instance, you may have a set character limit making attribution almost impossible.

### A General Template...

The real problem with attribution is sometimes there just isn't enough information to provide.  You may not even find ownership, title, copyright, etc. for the image your linking.  What you can do is simply attribute it from where you found it:

```
<hr>
<sup>*</sup> Source:  [Example Site](https://www.example.com). Adapted for this answer; see arrows and highlights for emphasis.
```

---

Again, a reasonable effort to attribute the work should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanx for the detailed and helpful answer... ;-)

Comment: Fantastic answer, @allan.  Thanks for providing this for us!